# What are the session variables which are to be validated in the whole application after successful Google OAuth Login

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

I have implemented Google OAuth login on my website. A user signs in using his/her Google Account, reaches my welcome page & now on my welcome page & other subsequent pages/scripts what are the variables which I need to validate to authenticate & check whether the user is logged in or not. Right now am just doing this :

```
checklogin.php (using it in require_once in all my subsequent php scripts)

if(isset ( $_SESSION['access_token'] ))
{

  //logged in 
}
else
{
   //NOT LOGGED IN

    header('location:login.php');

}
```

Do I need to check the value also of the access token & any other security variables to make my login inspection process more robust ? If yes, then how can it be checked ? Or is this check just sufficient enough ?

Comment: Assuming you are using the php client library it should handle all that for you you have an access token you should be good.

Comment: @DalmTo : Am using the process given on the Google Tutorials for OAuth PHP Login. Any specific library are you requiring ?

Comment: The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app#example) quite clear on this. Use `if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {` to check if a user is authenticated.

Comment: @DalmTo : am following the process of getting a client id and secret and then using them in the libraries given online and completing the process. An access token is generated automatically which changes on every login which am using to validate the login.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus : So you mean no value check, nothing, its all completely secure? If a user just for a simple hack, sets the access token in his php scripts using $_SESSION['access_token''] = 'foo' and runs it then again my condition will return true and he will just jump in my website and view all the private data of any user ? Ok so what do I use to assign every user a specific code / userid ? Is it the google profile id, but it must be with all programmers out there

Comment: @MonkeyZeus :  Ok so what do I use to assign every user a specific code / userid ? Is it the google profile id, but it must be with all the programmers out there, what will be the unique code for my each user ? Do I need to generate a hash key using the Google profile id and use it

Comment: If a user is able to arbitrarily set `$_SESSION['access_token']` then your web server has either been pwned or your code is thoroughly insecure.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus : is there something  unique which Google API returns for each its  user which I can use to fetch data of each user individually ?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus : " your code is thoroughly insecure" ??? what security are you referring to??  Please guide me

Comment: Go and read the tutorial, steps 4 and 5 in specific.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167188/discussion-between-sqlchild-and-monkeyzeus).

Answer (score 1):

Ripped from comment

> $_SESSION['access_token''] = 'foo' and runs it then again my condition will return true and he will just jump in my website and view all the private data of any user?

If you are really woried that someone will do this then the best thing to do would be to validate your access token against the tokeninfo endpoint.  [Doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#validate-access-token)

> https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=[access_token]

Am not really sure how you think a user could do this as your talking about a session variable in the browser.  However browser hacking is not my specialty.

**UserInfo endpoint**

Another option is to check the user info end point.  All identity servers have this endpoint which returns info about the current user. Because you are requesting the profile scope you should be able to see this.

Request

```
GET www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me 
Authorization: Bearer ya29.GluEBbGJOYKQ0gcDAFvU2iRKotG-a6MvbyNP6mUUk96RDKJHIFOR_RKiWxl8vQ01rbgy9lP_KmspvrHDzHMZ_
```

Response

```
{
  "family_name": "Lawton", 
  "name": "Linda Lawton", 
  "picture": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-a1CWlFnA5xE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAl1I/UcwPajZOuN4/photo.jpg", 
  "locale": "en", 
  "gender": "female", 
  "email": "xxx@gmail.com", 
  "link": "https://plus.google.com/+LindaLawton", 
  "given_name": "Linda", 
  "id": "7200475532672775346", 
  "verified_email": true
}
```

The id is my internal id with google

Comment: @DalmTo : Ok great. Is there something unique which Google API returns for each of its user which I can use to fetch data of each user individually from my database and which uniquely identifies my users ?

Comment: @DalmTo : Also, as per your answer you mean that we can cross check the value of the access token ?

Comment: depends on what scopes you are authencating with assuming you are getting a id_token back as well you can decrypt it its a jwt.io and there is a userid in there thats googles internal user id.   However it really depends on your scopes diffrent apis have have the ablitty to get a users email address as well.

Comment: I dont normally bother validating the access token.   I normally just make a request to the api if it works then i know its good basicly i trust google.   But yes you can check that its valid using the token info endpoint

Comment: @DalmTo : yes i am getting the  id_token as well.. and the following : expires_in , id_token in this format : a.b.c-d-e-xx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx,   token_type : Bearer , created : 1521552493 and my scope code is : 
  $client->addScope("email");
  
  $client->addScope("profile");

Comment: @DalmTo : ok so what code i need to write to verify the endpoint ? Can you point to some link regarding this or can you just help me out with the code?

Comment: check my answer there are two you can pick from you will have to code the request yourself. they are both just http gets shouldn't be too hard